# $? is ignored when run from a Makefile but works fine when copy-pasted as a bash command

Tags: shell, makefile, pylint

I am trying to automatically run a command from a Makefile:

```
make lint: 
    pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc --disable=R,C,W1203,W0702,W0621 main.py || pylint-exit $?
```

and then run the command with:

```
make lint
```

I get the following error -

> usage: pylint-exit [-h] [-efail] [-wfail] [-rfail] [-cfail] PYLINTRC
> make: *** [Makefile:6: lint] Error 1

probably because the shell expects an integer at the end of the command, but there is none
because **it doesn't recognize the $? sign.**

if I run the same command directly as a bash command:

```
pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc --disable=R,C,W1203,W0702,W0621 main.py || pylint-exit $?
```

everything runs as expected:

> main.py:5:0: W0611: Unused numpy imported as np (unused-import)
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------ Your code has been rated at 9.76/10 (previous run: 9.76/10, +0.00)
>
> The following messages were raised:
>
> - warning message issued
>
> No fatal messages detected.  Exiting gracefully...

Is there a workaround for this kind of behavior - I guess it is something with the way wildcard signs are handled in Makefiles.

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that `$` introduces a `Makefile` variable. To refer to *shell* variable named `$?`, you need to write `$$?`.

Answer (score 3):

`$` is both a make and shell metacharacter. You'll need to escape it so make ignores it and passes it to the shell.

```
pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc --disable=R,C,W1203,W0702,W0621 main.py || pylint-exit $$?
```

Answer (score 2):

`$?` is a `make` parameter expansion. You want the `$?` to be passed literally to the shell that executes `pylint-exit`, by doubling the `$`.

```
make lint: 
        pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc --disable=R,C,W1203,W0702,W0621 main.py || \
          pylint-exit $$?
```